# Reconnect to known and paired web bluetooth device

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, bluetooth, thermal-printer

I have a web app which prints to a Bluetooth thermal printer. I managed to connect to the printer and print what I need just fine. I was wondering if there's a way to save the device info into the session or local storage, so the user isn't required to pair to the device every time.

My current code is as follows:

```
    const device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
      acceptAllDevices: true,
      optionalServices: [
        '000018f0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'
      ]
    });

    const server = await device.gatt.connect();
    const service = await server.getPrimaryService("000018f0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    const characteristic = await service.getCharacteristic("00002af1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
```

The idea is to have something like:

```
const device = await navigator.bluetooth.connect(deviceId);
// using the device's ID or address, name or whatever information is available from the first pairing.
```

Comment: Did u find any solution..?

Comment: No solution yet @Glen

Comment: This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61559185/web-bluetooth-auto-connect-to-paired-device